# SOAPUI Groovy UI Support mapping with arrays

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am attempting to return the `key` of an array without the value appended to it in the `UI prompt`.  However, using that I have at the moment I get both the Key and Value.

When using `log.info` the console just shows the `key` which is what I want. However, I'm not entirely sure why I get both in the `UI dialogue box`.

The end goal is to display multiple usernames which have email addresses associated to them in a drop down and get the respective value of the selected key from drop down.

This is what i have so far:

```
def map2  = new HashMap<String,String>()
map2.put("SP", "XXX@.co.uk")
map2.each{ k, v -> log.info "${k}"}

email = UISupport.prompt("Select User ","Select User", map2.each{ k, v    ->  "${k}"})
```

This is what the UI currently displays:

[image: Email Dropdown]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do:

Convert the keys into a list and pass that list to `prompt()` method, so that it can show the drop down.

Changed script:
**Updating as per the asker's comment** - pass the result of the drop drown selection value as key to the map so that email can be retrieved.

```groovy
import com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport
def map  = ["SP": "XXX@.co.uk", "TP": "abc@abc.com"]
def list = map.keySet() as List
assert list instanceof List
email = map[UISupport.prompt("Select User ","Select User",  list)]
log.info email
```

And it appears as below:

[image]

Now you can see the email is selected when user selects the dropdown value in the above screen.

Comment: thanks for the response. It does a good job and returning the names however i am having difficulties with assigning the value to the name. The script works fine and displays the two records however if i select SP i would want the value for email to be set to XXX@co.uk - if thats possible?

Comment: You do not want key, but value, is that right? Email should have value of it, correct?

Comment: ys that is correct so only the name should appear in the dialogue box for the user to select but the email variable should hold the value of the key

Comment: Yes, updated the answer, have a look, please. And thank you for clarifying.